# Algorithms to re-order elements in array so that adjacents are similar

Tags: python, sorting

I am looking for a solution to this problem using Python. I need to grab an 2D array and re-arrange it so that the resulting array contains elements with values similar to the values around it. In other words, I need to transform a randomly populated array into an array with some sort of structure, clumps, etc, but maintaining the original distribution of values.
This seems hard to code, but I know that there must be some type of algorithm that could help me achieve this. I asked ChatGPT about it but it could not come up with the answer.
Thanks in advance. Maybe if someone could point out the name of a method ...

Comment: Please include input, output and your code attempt!

Comment: Kinda sounds like a KMeans type of question. Search around about it and see if that fits what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the following to solve this problem. Again I needed to reorder items in an array to end up with some sort of structure, i.e. 2D gaussian or even N 2D gaussian.
What I did is first create an array with the same dimensions as the one I want to reorder. This array is the structure seed. If I need a radially distribution in the reordered array, then the structure seed can be a 2G gaussian centered in the middle of the array.
Now, I can reshape the structure array into a single dimension. After this I reorder the elements from smallest to biggest, and then I get the indexes that would do the reverse of this operation, the indexes that would go back from the ordered 1D array to the original 1D. Finally I apply these inedexes to the original reshaped array.
The idea is that the highest value of the original array (the want I need to reorder) is going to be in the same position as the structure seed array. The same with the lowest value and so on.